# Filter an array in javascript with 2 property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular

And Here is the Array:

[image]

If someone's result + GMath is more than others I want to place him first in the array.

I'm making an angular app. I need to filter it for the app. If you need the template or the ts file just comment in below.

Comment: Are you wanting to filter (things removed) or sort (everything still there just in some order) or both?

Comment: `place him first in the array.`  That's not a filter, it s a sort.. So do you just want the array sorting by "result + GMath"?

Comment: There is no array here, you can't sort this without an array of items.

Comment: @Get_Off_My_Lawn: Please check now. I have added the array.

Comment: @Keith Yes i want to shorting by result + GMath

Comment: data.sort((itemA, itemB) => (itemB.a + itemB.b) - (itemA.a + itemA.b)); Where 'a' and 'b' are your keys result, GMath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to subtract the sum of `a` from the sum of `b` like this:

```js
let arr = [
  {result: 5, GMath: 5},
  {result: 2, GMath: 8},
  {result: 4, GMath: 10},
  {result: 1, GMath: 1}
]

arr.sort((a, b) => (b.result + b.GMath) - (a.result + a.GMath))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @Moumitaakter, be aware that you exclude IE users and people using "old" versions of their more modern browser -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: your code does work. But I don't understand 
arr.sort((a, b) => (b.result + b.GMath) - (a.result + a.GMath))
this line. Could you be more spesific. And why there is a - between two brackets

Answer (score 1):

```
// const obj = { admissionStudents: {...} }; // assuming this is the object to begin with
let keys = Object.keys(obj.admissionStudents);
keys.sort((a, b) => {
  return (obj.admissionStudents[b].result + obj.admissionStudents[b].GMath) - (obj.admissionStudents[a].result + obj.admissionStudents[a].GMath);
});
```

Now `keys` will be sorted, so frame the object using this.

New list,

```
newList = [];
keys.forEach((key) => {
  newList.push(obj.admissionStudents[key]);
});
```

`newList` will be the sorted list.

Hope it helps.